# STR Instruction fails, it doesn't store the value it's meant to store

Tags: assembly, lc3

I'm trying to implement a code that compares 2 numbers and stores in the register R1 the largest.
The following code is doing the job:

```
    .ORIG 0x300

    V1: .FILL 0x007
    V2: .FILL 0x020

    LD R2, V1 ;R2=V1
    LD R3, V2 ;R3=V2
    AND R4, R4, #0
    ADD R4, R4, R2 ;R4=R2
    AND R5, R5, #0
    ADD R5, R5, R3 ;R5=R3
    NOT R5, R5
    ADD R5, R5, #1 ;R5=-R4
    ADD R4, R4, R5
    BRN SECOND_BIGGER
    LD R1, V1
    JSR END
    SECOND_BIGGER:
     LD R1, V2

    END:
     .END
```

But when I tried to replace the part where I copy the 2 values on the registers R4 and R5 it stopped working:

```
.ORIG 0x300

V1: .FILL 0x007
V2: .FILL 0x020

LD R2, V1 ;R2=V1
LD R3, V2 ;R3=V2
STR R4, R2, #0
STR R5, R3, #0
NOT R5, R5
ADD R5, R5, #1 ;R5=-R4
ADD R4, R4, R5
BRN SECOND_BIGGER
LD R1, V1
JSR END
SECOND_BIGGER:
 LD R1, V2

END:
 .END
```

The code gets executed but displays the wrong result, any idea of the reason?

Comment: What's is the value in and purpose of R4 when you `ADD R4, R4, R5`

Comment: To compare R4 and R5, I negate R5 and do R4+R5, if that's negative, it means R5>R4 (the original values)

Comment: Yes, but the value in it?  The `STR` instruction has no register targets, only 2 register sources.  It stores the value held in the 1st register source into memory using the value held in the 2nd register source as the base pointer of where/at-what-address to store in memory.  Because you're not using it right, R4 never has a good/meaningful value, only that as given at start by the simulator.

Comment: You also are executing data as the first part of your program, kind of a bad idea, generally speaking.  Have you tried single stepping through this?  If not, give it a shot, should only take a few minutes.

Comment: I would like to copy the value contained in R2 in R4, I guess I'm using the wrong instruction or a bad way to do that actually, how should I change that line to make R4 contain the value of R2?

Comment: Use the add with immediate form, for example: `ADD R4, R2, #0`.  The value in R2 will be added with 0 and placed into R4.  That's your basic register to register copy/move.

Comment: Yeah that's what I did in the first version but I was trying to replicate it with LDR or STR but I guess I've misunderstood the functionalities of those instructions

Comment: Yes, such addition of 0 is more work than you need to copy one register to another (e.g. the addition operation is useless) but reusing existing instructions makes the hardware simpler, and even though in theory that could run faster (by forgoing the addition) likely won't change the overall cycle time, and would require more hardware and possibly occupation of encodings.

Comment: Yeah, the loads and stores are for copying data between CPU registers and memory locations.

Comment: Oh ok, my bad, thank you. Could you please answer the question so I can select your answer as the correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the add with immediate form, for example:  `ADD R4, R2, #0`.  The value in `R2` will be added with `0` and placed into `R4`.  That's your basic register to register copy/move.

Addition of 0 is more work than you need to copy one register to another (e.g. the addition operation is useless) but reusing existing instructions makes the hardware simpler, and even though in theory one that doesn't involve addition could run faster (by forgoing the addition) that likely won't change the overall cycle time, and would require more hardware and possibly occupation of encodings.

The loads and stores are for only for copying data between CPU registers and memory locations.

Comment: The normal way would be `MOV R4, R2`, no?  Of course if you really want to use `ADD` you can.

Comment: @NateEldredge, LC-3 is like MIPS, only *without* the pseudo instructions, at least the implementations that I know.